# Creating Hugging face model takes too much time

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am training a model in AutoTrain in Hugging face website, everytime it takes too much time.
Is it normal? I tried several project types and many different datasets but all of them did the same.
How long it will be ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL0gQ.png)

Comment: Your question (in fact a mere observation) will eventually be closed. In the future, ensure you provide much more information, such as the exact datasets, the hardware configuration, the entire code used; in case you provide such scarce information all the questions will be closed.

Comment: I don't understand your last reply. I am watching the tag, I try to answer your question and help you but honesly given the information there is nothing I can do to help you.

Comment: Are you using a machine with some power or an old dog? Ie less than 8g of ram, hard disk full ?

Comment: I'm using intel i5 core, windows 11 and with 120 GB free on hard disk (C).